# Using Python & Selenium, how to extract the text from HTML containing the <p> tag

Tags: python, selenium

This I know is a very simple question. I'm quite sick and trying to finish up this presentation and my brain just doesn't seem to be working right.

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<p>id="script_id">1</p>
```

Comment: The HTML code is as follows:

<p id="script_id">1 </p>

Answer (score 0):

The HTML in it's current form is invalid and ideally it should have been:

```
<p id="script_id">1</p>
```

---

To locate the element with text as ***1*** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *id*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "script_id")
  ```
- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p#script_id")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[@id='script_id']")
  ```

---

To extract the text ***1*** from the element ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *ID* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "script_id"))).text)
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *`get_attribute("innerText")`*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p#script_id"))).get_attribute("innerText"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`get_attribute("innerHTML")`*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[@id='script_id']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Answer (score 0):

If your text is `id="script_id">1` then you may use the below:

```
x = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'p').text
print(x)
```

Output:

```
id="script_id">1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But note that `p` may occur in many places and just not this line, and hence relying on just the `p` tag is not advisable at all in a larger picture. If it is just the purpose of this line, it would be ok, but in an application. You may have to look for some other connecting things and build a locator using all of them.

If somehow, the line you provided is faulty, i.e., if the `script_id` is indeed the attribute of `p`, i.e., `<p id="script_id">1`
Then, this would do:

```
x = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'script_id').text
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting 0 as the answer if i use the below selenium code.

Code1:-
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#showscripts"))).get_attribute("innerText"))

or

Code2:-
ele = self.get_element('element_to_be_clickable', 60, XPATH="//font/p[@id = 'showscripts']")
no_of_configured_robot_scripts = ele.text
print("No. of configured robot scripts is: " + no_of_configured_robot_scripts)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).